# Display/hide based on selected value on load is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a form where the user gets to pick 2 different widget types, based on a dropdown.  Each item in the drop down has very different form fields attached to it.  If I change the value, that works great.  The appropriate fields come up.  The problem I am having is on initial load of the form (the form itself is loaded via an ajax call), the appropriate fields are still hidden and not displayed.

Here is the section of code being displayed:

```
<tr id="numSliderSec1" class="numSliderSec">
  <td style="font-weight:bold;">
    Minimum Value:
  </td>
  <td width="20">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>
    <cfif isdefined("qRoundItemInfo.roundItemMinValue") and qRoundItemInfo.roundItemMinValue neq "" and qRoundItemInfo.roundItemMinValue>
      <input checked="checked" id="ItemMinValue" type="checkbox" onClick="roundsAdminEventHelper.updateItemMinValueEventHandler(#URL.RoundItemID#,this.value);" />
      <cfelse>
        <input id="ItemMinValue" type="text" onClick="roundsAdminEventHelper.updateItemMinValueEventHandler(#URL.RoundItemID#,this.value);" />
      </cfif>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr id="numSliderSec2" class="numSliderSec">
  <td colspan="3">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="numSliderSec3" class="numSliderSec">
  <td style="font-weight:bold;">
    Maximum Value:
  </td>
  <td width="20">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>
    <cfif isdefined("qRoundItemInfo.roundItemMaxValue") and qRoundItemInfo.roundItemMaxValue neq "" and qRoundItemInfo.roundItemMaxValue>
      <input checked="checked" id="ItemMaxValue" type="checkbox" onClick="roundsAdminEventHelper.updateItemMaxValueEventHandler(#URL.RoundItemID#,this.value);" />
      <cfelse>
        <input id="ItemMaxValue" type="text" onClick="roundsAdminEventHelper.updateItemMaxValueEventHandler(#URL.RoundItemID#,this.value);" />
      </cfif>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr id="numSliderSec4" class="numSliderSec">
  <td colspan="3">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="numSliderSec5" class="numSliderSec">
  <td slign="left">
    1
  </td>
  <td>
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td align="right">
    50
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="numSliderSec6" class="numSliderSec">
  <td colspan="3" id="sliderLoc">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="numSliderSec7" class="numSliderSec" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <td colspan="3">
    <label for="amount">
      Default Value:  
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="itemDefaultValue" readonly style="border:0; color:##f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="numTextBoxSec" class="numTextBoxSec">
  <td style="font-weight:bold;">
    Default Value:
  </td>
  <td width="20">
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>
    <cfif isdefined("qRoundItemInfo.roundItemDefaultValue") and qRoundItemInfo.roundItemDefaultValue neq "" and qRoundItemInfo.roundItemDefaultValue>
      <input checked="checked" id="ItemDefaultValue" type="checkbox" onClick="roundsAdminEventHelper.updateItemDefaultValueEventHandler(#URL.RoundItemID#,this.value);" />
      <cfelse>
        <input id="ItemDefaultValue" type="text" onClick="roundsAdminEventHelper.updateItemDefaultValueEventHandler(#URL.RoundItemID#,this.value);" />
      </cfif>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Here is the javascript/jquery. This is the code on the bottom of the page to try and grab the selected value when the page loads and display the appropriate fields:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var e = document.getElementById("itemWidgetType");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
   var initWidgetTypeSelected='#sItemTypeName#';
   if( initWidgetTypeSelected === 'Numeric')
   {
        if(strUsr == 'Slider')
        {
           alert('You are here');
           $('##numSliderSec1').css('display','table-row');
           $('##numSliderSec2').css('display','table-row');
           $('##numSliderSec3').css('display','table-row');
           $('##numSliderSec4').css('display','table-row');
           $('##numSliderSec5').css('display','table-row');
           $('##numSliderSec6').css('display','table-row');
           $('##numSliderSec7').css('display','table-row');
           $('##numTextBoxSec').css('display','none');
        }
        else
        {
           alert('##no...you are here');
           $('##numSliderSec1').css('display','none');
           $('##numSliderSec2').css('display','none');
           $('##numSliderSec3').css('display','none');
           $('##numSliderSec4').css('display','none');
           $('##numSliderSec5').css('display','none');
           $('##numSliderSec6').css('display','none');
           $('##numSliderSec7').css('display','none');
           $('##numTextBoxSec').css('display','table-row');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is too much of code and relevant pieces are missing, such as the `select`. Pls create a demo in a fiddle for us to be able to debug/help you. For a client side related question, post the generated HTML as opposed to the server side/pre-generated code.

Comment: Not only is it too much code, those of us who refuse to use horizontal scrollbars are not avaialable to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what you wrote, this seems like a timing thing. The `$(document).ready(` is not fired when called in a AJAX loaded page, because the document itself has already loaded. If I were you, I would put this function as a callback of the AJAX call that loads the form.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try that.